# Can Aspire One D260 run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

If so then I am going to install it formatting Windows XP.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is not the best choice for your Acer Aspire One D260. A better choice for quicker performance would be Xubuntu 14.04 32-bit which will be supported by updates until April, 2017. See: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) for more detailed information about hardware specs/*buntu releases/performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely can. Even Aspire One D250 can, which is a bit simpler. But anyway, if you run installation and can see that it goes up to the screen when it offers you "Try" or "Install", that means it can work at the particular hardware. Because by the time you see this screen the Linux Kernel and most subsystems are running. As they are the same that go into your machine this proves it is going to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on your laptop. [Click Here.](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-11.04-to-Replace-Windows)

You can also install with USB drive.

Click "Replace Windows XP with Ubuntu" for replace.

If you don't want to remove XP, then select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP".